# How to store a cookie in Android

Tags: java, android, http

I would like to know please how may I store an http session cookie and make it accessible from the rest of my activites other than the LoginActivtiy ?

Comment: You'd store it in a Singleton somewhere.  Or pass it between every activity, but generally the singleton is more convenient.

Comment: Use SharedPreferences : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Thanks guys for your tips